# Constructor suppressing not working with PowerMock+Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a class that implements singleton as

```
public class UMR {

private static UMR umr =  new UMR();

private MR mr;

private UMR(){
    this.mr = MR.getInstance();
}

public static UMR getInstance() {
    return umr;
}

}
```

and here is my test method code

```
@Test
public void test(){

    suppress(constructor(UMR.class));   

    mockStatic(UMR.class);

    UMR umr = PowerMockito.mock(UMR.class);

    when(UMR.getInstance()).thenReturn(umr);    

    System.out.println("End");

}
```

annotations used and imports:

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.constructor;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.suppress;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({UMR.class})
```

I do not want the private constructor to be called but it still calls the constructor even after suppressing the constructor successfully in first statement.

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I tried with java version 6 and 7 both and downloaded jar files from powermock github download page https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Isn't the problem to do with when the static constructor gets called. I think it gets called the moment you use the class. So I think the reference to the class in `suppress(constructor(UMR.class));` may be invoking the static initialization of UMR before you've managed to suppress its constructor.

Comment: First statement always get executed and it actually adds the private constructor to suppression list. Problem is when the second or third wither of the statement gets executed.

Comment: The second or third what of the statement? Can you show more of the problem?

Comment: Second and third line of the test case.

Comment: This is something i am trying to do. http://buckybits.blogspot.in/2011/11/testing-singletons-and-static-classes.html

Answer (score 0):

An constructor in this line is called before the constructor is suppressed.

```
private static UMR umr =  new UMR()
```

You have to use the `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor` in this case.

Comment: Where should I put this annotation , in which class ?

Comment: You should use add to test class. More information you can find [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior). Section "Suppress static initializer"

Answer (score -1):

Could you move to a lazy initialising singleton pattern?

```
public class UMR {
    private static UMR umr;

    private MR mr;

    private UMR(){
        this.mr = MR.getInstance();
    }

    public static UMR getInstance() {
        // double locked lazy initializing singleton
        if (umr==null) {
            synchronized(UMR.class) {
                // when we get here, another thread may have already beaten us
                // to the init
                if(umr==null) {
                    // singleton is made here on first use via the getInstance
                    // as opposed to the original example where the singleton
                    // is made when anything uses the type
                    umr = new UMR();
                }
            }
        }
        return umr;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code I testing is legacy I can modify it as you said.